# Read n lines into a [String]

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to read `n` lines of content into a List of Strings. I've tried several variations of the code below, but nothing worked.

```
main = do
  input <- getLine
  inputs <- mapM getLine [1..read input]
  print $ length input
```

This throws the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> IO b0'
                with actual type `IO String'
    In the first argument of `mapM', namely `getLine'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: inputs <- mapM getLine [1 .. read input]
    In the expression:
      do { input <- getLine;
           inputs <- mapM getLine [1 .. read input];
           print $ length input }
```

And

```
main = do
  input <- getLine
  let inputs = map getLine [1..read input]
  print $ length input
```

throws

```
 Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> b0'
                with actual type `IO String'
    In the first argument of `map', namely `getLine'
    In the expression: map getLine [1 .. read input]
    In an equation for `inputs': inputs = map getLine [1 .. read input]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: By the way, `inputs <- mapM (const getLine) [1 .. read input]` does exactly what you need. The problem is that you try to map `getLine` over numbers `[1 .. n]` but `getLine` isn't a function. By using `const`, you turn it into a function that just ignores its first argument.

Comment: @Vitus that is worthy as another answer, i'll +1 it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [`replicateM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) from `Control.Monad`:

```
main = do
  input <- getLine
  inputs <- replicateM (read input) getLine
  print $ length inputs
```

In the spirit of give a man a fish / teach a man to fish: You could have found this yourself by searching [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

You have:

- an action to perform of type `IO String`
- a number of times to perform that action (type `Int`)

You want:

- an action of type `IO [String]`

So you could [search Hoogle for `(IO String) -> Int -> (IO [String])`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28IO+String%29+-%3E+Int+-%3E+%28IO+[String]%29). `replicateM` is the first hit.

Comment: Thanks for the Hoogle hint in addition to the answer. This is what makes stackoverflow great!

Answer (score 2):

One other way you can do this action is by using the pure replicate and the `sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)`
 tool. Lets say first we will ask for a count and then ask for that many integers to print their sum on the terminal.

```
sumCountManyData :: IO ()
sumCountManyData = putStr "How many integers to sum..? "
                   >>  getLine
                   >>= sequence . flip replicate getLine . read
                   >>= print . sum . map read
```

Comment: This seems like a question for beginners (which I am), and it would help a lot to have a simple explanation of what this is doing.  For instance, explain that (read) converts to the required type (int), then (flip replicate getLine) calls (replicate (number from read) getLine) to call getLine the given number of times, and finally sequence converts to an IO.